# std::threads are managed in user or kernel space?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

As I wrote in the title, I would like to know if c++ stantard threads are managed in user or kernel space.

Thank you.

Comment: On which platform? As far as the standard is concerned, both options are equally valid.

Comment: The standard doesn't specify, but given the degree to which kernel threads have come to dominate, I think it's safe to guess that most implementations are likely to use kernel threads.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "kernel" in C++. Your question does not apply to C++ as a language.

Comment: I'm talking about an aspect of the C++ standard. I'm not claiming that in C++ it exists a kernel. Which tags do you suggest?

Comment: Are these two options binary? Or just the end of a scale? AFAICT there's always a small bit from `std::thread` running in user space even if the heavy lifting is done in kernel space.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As happens almost always, the standard doesn't mandate any particular implementation, it just requires that the exhibited behavior conforms to its rules.

Thus, the particular implementation is free to choose; on the other hand, probably many implementations will be based on boost.thread (on which the `std::thread` proposal is based), so we can look at it to have an idea.

This library uses pthreads on POSIX and Windows threads on Win32. Win32 threads are definitely kernel threads, but pthreads *on their own* are just yet another *interface*, which could be implemented both in user space and in kernel space (although almost any recent UNIX kernel provides facilities to implement them in kernel space).

So: `std::thread` can be anything, although, on "mainstream" PC operating systems/implementations, it's very likely that you'll get kernel threads. If for some reason you need to know more, check your compiler's documentation.

Comment: IIRC, Dinkumware's thread implementation is a cleanroom implementation, not Boost derived, and it too uses kernel threading.

Answer (score 4):

The interface is [designed around pthreads](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1815.html), but it is up to the implementer of the libc++ to decide what to use.